# Have multiple X Axis or Point Y data with the correct X axis value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, livecharts

Excuse me for my English.

I develop inC# WPF MVVM.

I try to use LiveCharts, it works, but I have a little problem with my data. The data set is a measurements from a device. There are max 3 curves. However I have no idea of the input data in advance.

The device that measures data, captures only one measurement (Y axis) at a time and therefore the date and time (X axis) linked to the measurement is never the same for each measurement.

In my example that I have on my desk, the device returns me 2 x 64 measurements, LivesCharts must superimpose these 2 curves.

I haven't tested it yet, but I found a way to create multiple X axes and bind these axes to the data. But it takes up a lot of space, because the labels of these axes being the date and time for each measurement. It's not great.

My predecessor (whom I replace) started with the idea of adding missing data to each curve.
That is to say to create a curve with, in the example, 128 data on the 2 curves, and therefore he adds the missing data by copying the value of the previous data. It's not great either.

The ideal would be to have a single X axis with the 128 values, and that each point (64 measurements) of each curve, point to the date that corresponds to it.

Is this "ideal solution" possible with LiveCharts?

[EDIT]
The data of each curve is therefore:
A date with time (X axis),
A float (Y axis).

Here is a small example with Excel:
I have 2 curves with 10 measurement points each which gives me 20 measurement points in all. Only one point on each date.

I took hours, because Excel did not want to show me a Date + time. But I would have a date + time.

[Exemple with Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iQuV.png)

The vertical lines (red and green) are there only to clearly see the points of the 2 curves, I don't need them for my project.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Two questions for you: 1) are you saying that you do not know the format and type of the input data that is being measured? 2) can you show what your input and what your expected output look like?

Comment: I edited my post as you requested., Thank